# Unity visual GUI editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity development, and struggling with GUI, I need to create complex menus in Unity. Do you know about good and free GUI development packages for Unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140) is most widely used in commercial game development. It's not free, but it has a free trial edition that you can use to learn. [Here's the link](http://www.tasharen.com/get.php?file=NGUI) to the free version download.

Comment: Thanx couldn't find the trial version, there is only paid, can you point me where I can find it?

Comment: Added download link to the answer.